# How to move Facebook Audience Network banner ad to bottom instead of top of screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-audience-network

This is the code that is provided from FB but this ad is placed on the top banner and I would like it fit to the bottom banner. Is there an easy fix to change the location for the FB ads? Also, the implementation is working and test ads are running.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  FBAdView *adView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID
                         adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner
                         rootViewController:self];
  [adView loadAd];
  [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can move the banner by changing its frame like this:

```
FBAdView *adView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID
                         adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner
                         rootViewController:self];

adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
[adView loadAd];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```